# How people inject malicious code on my webpage?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, code-injection

we have several web pages and one of them (Wordpress one) have been infected with a malicious malware code injected on it. The code had created a redirect to ads page. It has his own user and downloads plugins and themes. We have already deleted it, but I was thinking....
If I have the forms with the correct security, how could be possible to inject this in a web page?
I've searched, but normally people talk about how fix it, not how it happened, for future prevents it.
Some suggestions?

Comment: Your entire site is suspect and should be wiped out. Then reinstall everything from your backup. There is no "safe" way to know what may or may not have been infected.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to several reasons but most common one is warez themes with back-doors. If you are using such theme, it is likely that there is a back-door which allows attacker to do certain changes. And if that's the case, i highly recommend switching to an alternate theme.

Another one could be brute-force. There have been an mass attack on many wordpress websites in 2018. If your hosting provider doesn't have DDoS or anti-spam mechanisms, they may have got your credentials for login.

If you would like to take immediate action, just change your login page url. Simple yet strong solution against bots. For this, you could use a plugin such as [WPS Hide Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/), or you can just implement a 2FA using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-2-factor-authentication/) for example